# Regex to pull 2nd-level domain out of text

Tags: regex, pcre

My splunk logs contain the following data:

```
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT , URL: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html, TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
```

I want to pull out only the "rexegg.com" but I currently get "www.rexegg"

Closest I've got: `(?i)(?:http:\/\/|https:\/\/)(?P<test>(?<!,)\w*\.\w*)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regex to this:

```
(?i)https?:\/\/(?:[^. ]+\.)*(?P<test>[\w-]+\.[\w-]+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cJ6xP4/4)

Comment: I'm sorry, that returns the same values as my initial string

Comment: Nope, you need to check value of group called `test`. In the demo see **MATCH INFORMATION** on right hand side

Comment: Shame that your regex fails to match `www2` domains

Comment: I am using regex101.com to validate and your string does not return anything different. I'm not validating, I use these regex's to create field extractions in splunk. i've done this several times, I just can't figure out how to get it to return the last 2 "words" of my url string in my logs. there's not always a www in the logs either.

Comment: https://a248.e.akamai.net is in one of my log entries, but this is to always pull the 2nd level domain out of the log no matter the size. Whether it's http://yahoo.com http://mail.yahoo.com, etc... I always want akamai.net or yahoo.com. You can put TEST text all around it, I'm not posting more data from my logs.

Comment: I have updated regex but I'm sure there can be some edge cases where this will not work since URLs can vary a lot.

Comment: Actually, I replaced the hard space in your regex with a white space class for flexibility. (?i)https?:\/\/(?:[^.\s]+\.)*(?P<URL_Site>[\w-]+\.[\w-]+)